# NetBeans+Maven: основной код не видит пакеты зависимостей

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

День добрый.

Возникла такая проблема: к Maven-проекту была добавлена зависимость. Однако при попытке использования классов из нее в коде, NetBeans определила в строке импорта ошибку, мол, нет такого пакета. При этом автодополнение работает прекрасно и все пакеты видит.

Подключение зависимости:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Импорт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять, что не так. Все остальные зависимости прекрасно обрабатываются.

UPD: проблема решена, подсунула ему нужный jar локально, все заработало.

Comment: пакет точно присутствует в репозитории? 
приведите в теле вопроса полный трейс, пожалуйста

Comment: @SeniorAutomator да, пакет в репозитории точно есть. в вопрос поместить, к сожалению, пока не могу, так что вот так: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1z85kMRzxSRTjB6ZDJMVXRKYk0/view?usp=sharing если это то, что вы имели ввиду.

Comment: нет. стэктрейс ошибки, который выдает

Comment: в силу некоторых обстоятельств не компилировала код, а так NetBeans пишет вот что: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1z85kMRzxSRTjB6ZDJMVXRKYk0/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

в пакете `ru.CryptoPro.JCP` есть класс ***JCP***? импортируете руками или нетбинс так вставляет? попробуйте просто `import ru.CryptoPro.JCP.*`

Comment: Класс в пакете есть, импортирую руками, импорт со звездочкой не помогает, та же ошибка.